# StreamReader - how to ignore reading comma characters

Tags: c#, winforms, streamreader

C# winforms app - I'm using a `StreamWriter` to write a `.csv` file (reading from DataGridView).

Because it is a `.csv` file, how can I tell the `StreamReader` not to read comma characters from DatagridView (if any)?

Answer (score 5):

There is no method with **StreamReader** to read text without specific charracter.

> You can read first then store it in temporary string and use the
>   string.Replace() method to discard comma.

```
string.Replace(",","");
```

> then write to csv file.

Comment: If I make a temporary string - how to read them again correctly, because its comma delimiters are in fact - DataGridView cells?

Comment: Don't use a comma as a delimter.  I found that out the hard way a few times use something else, that is highly unlikely your user will ever use, I like §  or ¥, mainly because they look cool,  this one is simple and I have never seen it used anywhere ¦   no it is not a semi-colon, it is called a broken bar.

Answer (score 4):

> c# winforms I'm using a StreamWriter to write a csv.file

This sentence is scary. Checkout the [following article](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp). And then use a [real CSV parser](http://www.filehelpers.com/).